# How to get max product of 3 numbers from a list or dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contain numbers. Now I want to get the max product of N (N is integer >=2) columns for each row.  The only ideal I got so far is to use a complex loop. How can I do it quickly? Thank you for helping :)

```
> df <- data.frame(rep(4:6,time=2),rep(6:4,time=2),rep(6:8,2),rep(8:10,2))
> colnames(df) <- c(1,2,3,4)
> 
# ideal result
df
  1 2 3  4 maxproductof3
1 4 6 6  8    288
2 5 5 7  9    315
3 6 4 8 10    480
4 4 6 6  8    288
5 5 5 7  9    315
6 6 4 8 10    480
```

Comment: Will the numbers always be positive

Comment: How do you get 405 from the second row?

Comment: @Dason Sorry my mistake. I have corrected that.

Comment: Will the numbers always be positive?  If not are you looking for the max result in terms of absolute value or are you taking the sign of the result into consideration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `apply` and `sort`:

```
df$maxproductof3 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) prod(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]))
```

**Result:**

```
  1 2 3  4 maxproductof3
1 4 6 6  8           288
2 5 5 7  9           315
3 6 4 8 10           480
4 4 6 6  8           288
5 5 5 7  9           315
6 6 4 8 10           480
```

Comment: Thank you~ Your answer is perfect but wiwh answered in the front of you. So I will take his as the answer. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @Codezy Not true... Look at the time stamp. I answered 1min earlier than he did.

Comment: xD both of you are 10 mins ago. But yeah I find out your answer is earlier.

Comment: @Codezy Yea, I agree it's very close. That's why I have no problem having both answers, even though they are essentially the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using apply...

```
N <- 3
df$maxproductof3 = apply(df, 1, function(row) prod(sort(row, decreasing=T)[1:N]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much ~

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `pmap`

```
library(tidyverse)
pmap_dbl(df, ~ c(...) %>% 
                   sort %>% 
                   tail(3) %>% 
                   prod) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, maxProductof3 = .)
#   1 2 3  4 maxProductof3
#1 4 6 6  8           288
#2 5 5 7  9           315
#3 6 4 8 10           480
#4 4 6 6  8           288
#5 5 5 7  9           315
#6 6 4 8 10           480
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)